How to render text from a custom database table into the page head?
I have a TYPO3 v13.2.1 website and I want to add data from a custom database table into a pages head tag.
Currently I am attempting
page.headerData {
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    table = my_custom_table
    select {
      selectFields = head_content
      max = 1
    }
   renderObj = COA
   renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = head_content
   }
  }
}


page is of type PAGE
headerData is of type CObj by default and can hold objects of type CONTENT
10 is of type CONTENT, where I base my code upon the documentation at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html#cobj-content

I don't know how to debug it. I can only tell, that the database query gets fired since when I am writing the table or column incorrectly, TYPO3 throws an error.
What am I doing wrong?
EDIT 1:
I checked the Typoscript rendering after applying another test and it looks like this:


I'm not quite sure, but I guess you need to use the record as field data for the renderObj, something similar to following:
page.headerData.10 = CONTENT
page.headerData.10.table = my_custom_table
page.headerData.10.select {
  selectFields = head_content
  max = 1
}
page.headerData.10.renderObj = COA
page.headerData.10.renderObj.10 = TEXT
page.headerData.10.renderObj.10.stdWrap.field = head_content
page.headerData.10.renderObj.10.stdWrap.wrap = |

Adopted from here https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html#apply-special-rendering
Note: You may use another headerData value, for example page.headerData.100 or so - maybe it is overriden later with anouter value ?

Thank you, but it sadly doesn't work either. I included the TypoScript record from the backend. It's not being overwritten

What is the content of your custom table "head_content" field ? And beside that, you do not have a condition - are you sure a correct is displayed ?
